# Nozzle material of Apollo Lunar Module ascent engine?

Tags: propulsion, apollo-program, engines

There are some photos of the Apollo Lunar Module ascent engine, see [1](https://howlingpixel.com/wiki/Ascent_Propulsion_System), [2](https://historicspacecraft.com/Lunar_Module.html), [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascent_Propulsion_System). The nozzle looks like being made of epoxy and fiberglass. The fibers are wound in two different directions.

Is it true or something different material?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've confirmed that it was made of "plastic" but not what type yet.

> The combustion chamber assembly consists of an engine case and mount
>   assembly and a plastic assembly, which includes the nozzle extension.
>   The engine case and mount assembly is bonded and locked to the plastic
>   assembly to form an integral unit. The plastic assembly provides
>   ablative cooling for the combustion chamber; it consists of the
>   chamber ablative material, the chamber insulator, the nozzle
>   extension ablative material, and a structural filament winding. The
>   chamber ablative material extends from the injector to an expansion
>   ratio of 4.6. The chamber insulator , between the ablative material
>   and the case, maintains the chamber skin temperature within design
>   requirements. The ablative material of the nozzle extension extends
>   from the expansion ratio of 4.6 to 45.6 ( exit plane) and provides
>   ablative cooling in this region. The structural filament winding
>   provides the structural support for the plastic assembly and ties the
>   chamber and nozzle extension sections together .

[Source](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/LM10HandbookVol1.pdf) "LM10 Handbook Volume 1" page 2.3-41 and 2.3-42 (pp. 296-7 in the 800+ page pdf)

This schematic confirms that the "structural filament winding" mentioned above was fiberglass.

[image]

[Source](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19730010173.pdf): Apollo Experience Report: Ascent Propulsion System

Comment: At first I wondered if the word "plastic" might be an adjective (as opposed to "elastic") but I guess not. Seeing as how weight minimization was so critical here and re-use out of the question, a plastic rocket nozzle, while astounding, sounds possible. I'd planned on getting something done today, but maybe I will just spend the rest of the day reading these documents!

Comment: Still looking for more info. Perhaps it's our old friend phenolic? https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22003/how-can-phenolic-resin-handle-rocket-engine-nozzle-temperatures/22004#22004

Comment: To fix the fiber glass windings, you need a liquid that transforms into a solid by polymerization. Using a thermoplastic material like PVC or polyamide will be difficult. There are bisphenol epoxy resins, [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoxy).