Why don't rocket engines use heat tiles on the inside?
I asked in chat about rocket engines not melting @ 3300°C despite steel melting at 1400°C. The two excellent answers were:

thermal mass was one answer
the propellants are often piped through tiny tubes or channels within the bell was a more sustainable(suitable for actually going high) one

What I don't get is why isn't ceramic insulation used on the inside of nozzles and even the combustion chamber. Could be extremely thin(like the orange paint-like foam on the main tank of the STS' but for heat instead of cold) but will still reduce ablative wear on the heat-transmitting metal alloy.
I would appreciate answers to the literal question(floor tiles hehe) as much as answers as to alternative solutions and most of all - an explanation why none of that seems to transpire. What the question is not about are load bearing material selection, active heat management, feasibility of using just a piece of iron for simple missions(bombing people).

In addition to @Uwe's comment pointing out Inconel is used instead of steel, I just now landed on the following Wikipedia quote:

Often, heat-resistant carbon-based materials are used, such as amorphous graphite or reinforced carbon–carbon.


Ceramics tend to crack or  break off in chunks. Some engines and motors do use ablative nozzles. https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22003/6944

Rocket engines develop incredible pressure in the combustion chamber (which is kind of the point when you think about it), and thermal tiles are probably not rated for that kind of mechanical stress. For instance, the F-1 engine on the Saturn V had a chamber pressure over 70 atm.

Thermal design of rocket nozzles is a pretty broad discipline.  Materials are selected with appropriate thermal properties, and then various other techniques are used to regulate the nozzle temperature to within its limits. I don't think ceramic tile is entirely ruled out--I'm almost positive aerospike designs have used ceramic tiles on the spike, but I can't find the example I'm looking for right now.

@Cadence yeah, cool, the ceramics fractures and scars the iron engine. That was going to get ablated anyway. I'm starting to feel it's something about the pressure and "scars" not being the correct verb but would appreciate an answer from someone that doesn't function on feelings solely. You can assume an ordinary de Laval.

@Vorac See, I had initially assumed you were talking about non-ablative heat tiles like on the Shuttle or Starship, specifically because your combustion chamber ablating during normal flight makes it far more difficult to analyze. It's hard enough to model all the complexities of the chamber without it changing underfoot.

this Q+A is relevant I think:  How are rocket nozzles made

Vibration is also very problematic.

There is also film cooling where a thin film of gaseous fuel is passed down the inside of the walls of the combustion chamber to carry away the heat.

There a better materials to build a rocket engine than steel, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inconel is used. The temperature limit is much lower than the melting point.  At the maximal temperature, most of the initial mechanical strength of the material should be available.

@Uwe that's already an answer - nothing less than what I had expected of You. "When heated, Inconel forms a thick, stable, passivating oxide layer protecting the surface from further attack."

The orange stuff on the ET was foam, not paint, and wasn't extremely thin.

Ceramics have been investigated over the years, but note that they still required active cooling when used in the combustion chamber - the sought advantage was weight, not the elimination of active cooling. As previously stated, composite ablative nozzles and chambers have been used. http://rocket-propulsion.info/resources/articles/Ceramic_Materials_For_LPRE.pdf https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/19451277.pdf

When considering a rocket engine design you want (among lots of other things) to maintain the highest pressure possible inside the combustion chamber, and the narrower nozzle throat, this will increase the speed of combustion products coming out of the nozzle.
The main issues I see with ceramic tiles are:

Ceramic tiles are incredibly good at isolating heat but really weak mechanically so they would get immediately destroyed by the pressure and vibrations. (There was a saying that you could actually pierce a shuttle ceramic tile with a pen)

You want the flow from the combustion chamber towards the nozzle to be as smooth as possible so it doesn't slow down. Tiles of any kind would break this smoothness, the fact that you would have edges, crevasses, even small ones, would be enough to cause considerable turbulence inside the engine, causing from the degradation of the performance up to the destruction of the engine.



<things to keep in mind: weak engineering, weak physics knowledge> First point is excellent but second is moot as I asked "Could be extremely thin" as in "some kind of film" in contrast to "someone's bathroom". Will wait for under a week and then probably accept Your excellent thoughts as a final answer.

Being super thin means the ceramic layer won't do much. The physical thickness of the tile is a big part of how it does what it does.

@Vorac What you're essentially asking is for Starlite to be brought back. Even then, I believe it was considered an ablative shield.
