# The structures in regenerative cooling method and structural strength?

Tags: rockets, propulsion, engines, liquid-fuel

Does the jacket of tubes used to cool the nozzle and combustion chamber in a rocket engine also give it some structural strength? Does it have any function relating to  withstanding the pressure of the byproduct gases, or is it for cooling purposes only?

Comment: The walls of the combustion chamber are exposed to the pressure inside and should withstand it.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this question: [How are rocket nozzles made?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22001/how-are-rocket-nozzles-made/22002#22002) In pictures there, you can see that the cooling jacket IS the nozzle in many cases.

In this picture I took of a flown, but scrapped SSME nozzle, you can see that the inside of the nozzle is constructed solely of the cooling tubes.

[image]

Here is a close-up.

[image]