# Layout of regenerative cooling tubing?

Tags: engine-design

In F1, and space shuttle engines (I think), the regenerative cooling tubing goes through the inner wall of the nozzle. The russian engines (RD-180 and likes) seem to have smooth inner and outer surfaces for the nozzle. However, I think the outer surface of the nozzle has the cooling tubing, which is then covered up by another sheet of metal. Is that correct? What are the advantages that either layouts may have over the other?

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22001/how-are-rocket-nozzles-made/22002#22002

Comment: In the F1 and SSME the cooling tubes *are* the nozzle.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Hi, thanks for the answer, and I assume you worked an entire lifetime on these engines. In the answer to the link you have provided, the Russian channel wall technology link is dead. Could you say in short what that is, or provide an alternate link. Google search does not turn up anything interesting.

Comment: It should be relatively easy to find by googling "channel wall rocket engine." For example https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=20180006324

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the dead link!

Comment: @OrganicMarble  And is what I think I observed with Russian nozzles correct? Are there any adantages to having the cooling channels outside, and having a rather simple metal cone as the main load bearing member?

Comment: Hopefully someone will come along and write a proper answer for you.